# MySQL select and split string (containing column name & value)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, split

I have a complex situation here. There are 3 tables (t1 t2 t3):

```
t1.attributes (type: longtext)
-----------------------
"1":"A","2":"0","3":0

t2.attr_id  t2.attr_name
------------------------
1           X
2           Y
3           Z

t3.value_id t3.value_name
----------------------------
0           Hi
```

I want a query generating the following result:

```
X  Y  Z
---------
A  0  Hi
```

In other words, firstly, break the string in t1 by comma, getting tuples of the form "1":"A".

Secondly, the first part "1" will be matched to t2 to get column name.

For the second part, if it is within a quotation "", such as "0", then just put 0. Otherwise, if it is 0 without "", match with t3 to get "Hi".

Any idea on how to do this complex task?

Comment: This is the most unnormalized data I have seen in a while.  You should consider scrubbing your data before you bring it into MySQL in some sort of tabular format.

Comment: Maybe using MySQL function `JSON_EXTRACT(...)` to get the first value and then use common SQL to get the other values. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths)